# Android Alarms too early

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm using android studio to develop an application that would retrieve the time information from the database and would set an alarm to prompt the user that it's time to drink the medicine, my problem is that the alarm goes on too early

for example the retrieved time is 12:50 AM and the current time is 12:40 AM
even though there's a 10 minutes difference the alarm goes off right away

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
try {
         Calendar Cnow = Calendar.getInstance();
         long now=Cnow.getTimeInMillis();
         Calendar time=Calendar.getInstance();
         time.setTimeInMillis(0);
         Date dTime=sdf.parse(strAlarmDate + " " + strTime1);
//example strAlarmDate="2015-09-27" and strTime1="12:50 AM" and now="12:40 AM" in millis
//dTime="...... 2015-09-27 00:50"
         time.setTime(dTime);
         //Date dNow=now.getTime();
         //time.setTime(date);
         //long trigger=time.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTimeInMillis();
         long trigger=time.getTimeInMillis()-now;
         if(trigger>0) {
             ctr++;
             Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
             i.putExtra("message", strMedname);
             i.putExtra("line", strLine);
             final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
             PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Login.this, _id, i, 0);
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//           am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pi);
//           am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pi);
             am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pi);
         }
     }catch(ParseException ex)
     {
          ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the alarm to go off at time `trigger` which is the time minus the current time.

You should pass `time.getTimeInMillis()` instead.

So replace the line with

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bas van Stein is correct. `AlarmManager` uses an absolute time: milliseconds since epoch, January 1, 1970. You are attempting to set it to a relative time: milliseconds from the time you are setting the alarm. `AlarmManager` interprets that as being some time very close to epoch, around January 1, 1970, at 12:10AM. Since that time is long since past, the alarm triggers immediately.

The solution is simply to use `time.getTimeInMillis()` in `set` instead of `trigger`.

Some other notes for doing this kind of work, since your app is similar in intention to mine:

- Most alarms since API 19 will be inexact, as Frank N. Stein pointed out. The degree of this inexactness depends on implementation and also how far in the future the alarm is created. For something like medicine which is probably at least daily, in all of my testing the alarm has fired within a minute of the intended time.
- You are using the current time as the `requestCode` in your `PendingIntent`. By setting this to a number that is meaningful to your program and storing that value, you can later update or cancel this alarm by recreating the same `PendingIntent`.
- From API level 23 and forward, urgent alarms like medication alarms should use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` to ensure that their alarm goes off during low power idle states. I do not yet know if using `set` with `RTC_WAKEUP` will be sufficient to ensure this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.